# Typescript infers object as never when checking if a conditional property exists

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I have a type called `T` that accepts a generic type `Str extends string`. If the `Str` extends `"hello"`, then the type `T` should have an additional property called `B`. Something like this:

```js
export type T<Str extends string> = {
  A: number;
} & (Str extends "hello" ? { B?: number } : {});
```

Based on that type, it behaves as follows:

```js
type T1 = T<"hello">; // type T1 = { A: number; B?: number | undefined; }
type T2 = T<"world">; // type T2  = { A: number; }
```

Now, I want to create a function that accepts this type as an argument, and add an extra logic based on the existence of property `B`:

```js
function t<Type extends string>(arg: T<Type>) {
  if ("B" in arg) {
    // ...
  }
}
```

Although, I get an error that `arg` inside the if statement is considered as `never`.

[See playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.5.4&ssl=14&ssc=1&pln=8&pc=1#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBDAnmYcAqAeAyjKdQzAB2AJgM5xm4CWRA5gHxwC8cA3gFBxwCCAXHCIBXALYAjYFADcHAL5wAZHAAUOPAWLk4AIgAWwADYGI2uAH52cAEJmBw8ZLjyBbWQEoZHJCnQBGFugYeobG2gxScAD0kQjIqGj+rGy8dqIS0ta2gmmOAD5wQqTAAGa0wCQRsl5x6ABMAZjaAO7QBiRhEdGxPmj1Acn82Q4ZVRzFhQDGMNQQRAgYaDUapBRUULSMygCGUHQCmIsoDG7sXHDUxSraVqa0cDt0J5zc3F3KYDtbIsCEUCcPdmAADdJGduBNZmQIAZgAA6Yx0ba7WFWDxnKpVIA)

Comment: Perhaps like this: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.5.4#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBDAnmYcAqwDOMA8BlGKOUGYAOwBNM5soBLMgcwD44BeOAbwCg44BBAFxwyAVwC2AI2BQA3NwC+cAGRwAFASIlyVOACIAFsAA2xiHrgB+LnABCl4WKky4S4ZzsO4oysABmDMAUrgCU8txIKHAAEiZmAGoAhvSJZPAcGNg4hnHmzOF+PgDGMHQQZAg4aMQgpJTUarGmEEkpaXAAPuhYuLQMLCHMasmMwmghXLxwdH7qIwB0thM8fHxF5ZgQxsDzZozDUIyLYVMKitxAA

Comment: @EgeÖzcan I believe you can post it as an answer

Comment: The thing is, I don't want B to be accepted in arg https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.5.4#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBDAnmYcAqwDOMA8BlGKOUGYAOwBNM5soBLMgcwD44BeOAbwCg44BBAFxwyAVwC2AI2BQA3NwC+cAGRwAFASIlyVOACIAFsAA2xiHrgB+LnABCl4WKky4S4ZzsO4oysABmDMAUrgCU8txIKHAAEiZmAGoAhvSJZPAcGNg4hnHmzOF+PgDGMHQQZAg4aMQgpJTUarGmEEkpaXAAPuhYuLQMLCHMasmMwmghXLxwdH7qIwB0thM8fHxF5ZgQxsDzZozDUIyLYVMKitwRaisCwgCMADQXfAD0z3AAAjCYALSgKCW-KBQaB2GgGCCiYzBMgQeCgOjYOBGKA7Ka2YQ+Cj+QIURQhIA

Comment: that doesn't work, sorry: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.5.4#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABFATACgIYCcDmAuRAbwEECwQBbAIwFMsBfRAHyNMXOroBpEAhMyrQYBKIgChEiGMESZcAOl6jCEyYggIAznAA2NeTrg45ORcIDcq+mPpA you can make it work via a discriminated union, but you need a key: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.5.4#code/C4TwDgpgBAglC8UDeMBcUB2BXAtgIwgCcAaKAawEsMATdAIgHMIMiKBjOgXwG4AoUSFABCCZGky4CJYemz4ipSjXoALAIYBnIVz79w0AMKi4AH2G6AZlgxtgFAPYYowAEwAKNYQboDASmS8UFAUFlAeXgB0StQI8Ih06lp0-kiBQVBsjhr2ADYQETn2DOEMEUK+fEGcvJxAA (to... discriminate)

Comment: @EgeÖzcan it will - https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.5.4#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABFATACgIYCcDmAuRAbwEECwQBbAIwFMsBfRAHyNMXOroBpEAhMyrQYBKIgChEiGMERoARLzlSk2HKMITJiCAgDOcADY0AdAbg5MuY72EBuTfTH0gA

but that's not my use case. And I'm afraid I can't use discriminated union in my example

Comment: it works if you are willing to use the "in" syntax with the named variant anyway: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.5.4#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBDAnmYcAqwDOMA8BlGKOUGYAOwBNM5soBLMgcwD44BeOAbwCg44BBAFxwyAVwC2AI2BQA3NwC+cAGRwAFASIlyVOACIAFsAA2xiHrgB+LnABCl4WKky4S4Z1cBKedyQo4ABImZgBqAIb0YWTwHBjYOIbB5sw+AGaiZADGMHQQZAg4aMQgpJTUakGmEOGR0XAAPuhYuLQMLJ7MahGMwmieXLxwdKnqerYWDHDd-Tx8fJl5mBDGwAB0ZoxdUIyrtt6DCorcQA

Answer (score 0):

It works if you explicitly name the variant:

```
export type Test<Str extends string> = {
  A: number;
} & (Str extends "hello" ? { B?: number } : { });

type HelloVariant = Test<"hello">;

function t<T extends (HelloVariant | Test<string>)>(arg: T) {
  if ("B" in arg) {
    console.log(arg.B);
  }
}
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.5.4#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBDAnmYcAqwDOMA8BlGKOUGYAOwBNM5soBLMgcwD44BeOAbwCg44BBAFxwyAVwC2AI2BQA3NwC+cAGRwAFASIlyVOACIAFsAA2xiHrgB+LnABCl4WKky4S4Z1cBKedyQo4ABImZgBqAIb0YWTwHBjYOIbB5sw+AGaiZADGMHQQZAg4aMQgpJTUakGmEOGR0XAAPuhYuLQMLJ7MahGMwmieXLxwdKnqerYWDHDd-Tx8fJl5mBDGwAB0ZoxdUIyrtt6DCorcQA)

Actually what needs to be named is the possibility of that string being a "hello". Here is more simplified version:

```
export type Test<Str extends string> = {
  A: number;
} & (Str extends "hello" ? { B?: number } : { });

function t<T extends (Test<"hello"> | Test<string>)>(arg: T) {
  if ("B" in arg) {
    console.log(arg.B);
  }
}
```

[Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.5.4#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBDAnmYcAqwDOMA8BlGKOUGYAOwBNM5soBLMgcwD44BeOAbwCg44BBAFxwyAVwC2AI2BQA3NwC%20cAGRwAFASIlyVOACIAFsAA2xiHrgB%20LnABCl4WKky4S4Z1cBKedwBmosgBjGDoIMgQcNGIQUkpqNQxsHEMTMz1WAB90LFxaBhZPZjUAQyhGYTRPLl44Ol91PVsLBjhSxiqePj5AsMwIY2AAOjNGErLB228ahUVuIA)